# How to store graph data in a php variable?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to get the number of likes of a particular page on my website and store it in an array. Stuck in middle, i figured out that i can get the number of likes along with other data by the following code:

```
/*$site="http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3a%2f%2xxxxxxxx.com/abc.php";
$graph= file_get_contents($site);
```

the output is as follows:

```
{"http:\/\/xxxxxxxx.com\/abc.php":{"id":"http:\/\/xxxxxxxx.com\/abc.php","shares":75,"comments":3}}
```

is there a way i can just store the number of likes i.e. in this case 75 in a php array?

I tried **explode();** but the problem is that the url that i would be using wont be of a constant length.

Comment: That data format is called JSON, so look up json_decode in the manual. Btw., if you would use the PHP SDK, it would do the necessary stuff for you automatically.

Comment: @CBroe yea i guessed it was JSON but was just curious if this can be done using PHP by the same output results. Thanks anyways

Comment: Why don't you use the PHP SDK? Its a lot easier and its more future-proof.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers, what if i have multiple like buttons on the same page and if they arent the like buttons for facebook pages but my website's particular pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a json string decode it, use json_decode you will get the output as array.
ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$array  = json_deocde($json_string, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Did get the values in array but a stupid question, it says 'Array (....[shares]=>75.....)' How do i get this to a variable? What index should i give to the array?

Comment: `$var = $array['shares'];`

Comment: I tried that , it didn't work. It gave a following **Notice: Undefined index: shares in C:\xampp\htdocs\graphapi.php on line 19**